# how to use the for /f command when the file has a space

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm new to cmd, having trouble with this:

```
md "C:\kysumicomp"
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`CALL DIR /b /s "C:\Program Files" ^| FIND "javac.exe"`) do
   copy "%%a" "C:\kysumicomp"
pause
```

What I am trying to achieve is a batch file that that will find the javac.exe file then copy it to C:\kysumicomp but I don't want it to be an absolute path so if my java updates the batch will still work.

Comment: Why is this question tagged java?

Comment: @TedHopp I suspect because there's somewhere a file named `javac.exe` in script! :P

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... your real question (despite the title of the question) seems to be:

> What I am trying to achieve is a batch file that that will find the
>   javac.exe file then copy it to C:\kysumicomp...

I think you're overcomplicating things.

Try this (refer to `FOR /?` for more information on the `/R` option):

```
FOR /R "%ProgramFiles%" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" COPY /Y "%%~a" C:\kysumicomp\
)
```

Note that this will copy *all* occurances of `javac.exe` to your directory, one overwriting the other (an issue with your original solution also). If you want to stop after the first hit, you need to exit the loop early:

```
FOR /R "%ProgramFiles%" %%a IN (.) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" (
       COPY "%%~a" C:\kysumicomp\
       GOTO END
    )
)
:END
```

Finally, a simpler solution might by to copy the `javac.exe` that is in your `PATH`, provided it is.

```
FOR %%a IN (javac.exe) DO (
    IF EXISTS "%%~$PATH:a" (
       COPY "%%~$PATH:a" C:\kysumicomp\
    )
)
```

Then, since you're question title already doesn't match what you're trying to achieve, I wonder if you really need to do something totally different altogether. Why are you copying `javac.exe` to your directory in the first place?

Comment: i stilll seem to get the same error:C:\>copy "C:\Program" "C:\kysumicomp"
The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

The default field delimiters in `for /f` are space and tab characters. To solve your problem you have to redefine the delimiters. Use `delims=` with a character that will never appear inside a path, for example `|`. There is also another problem. Imagine having a directory `c:\Program Files\javac.exe\`. Your code will copy all the files inside that directory to C:\kysumicomp. But you don't really have to use `find`, `dir` is enough:

```
md "C:\kysumicomp"
for /f "delims=| usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b /s "C:\Program Files\javac.exe"`) do (
   copy "%%a" "C:\kysumicomp"
)
pause
```

Christian's solution is also a good one, I believe the only thing to change is to include the file name in `copy`:

```
FOR /R "%ProgramFiles%" %%a IN (.) DO (
  IF EXIST "%%~a\javac.exe" (
    COPY "%%~a\javac.exe" "C:\kysumicomp"
    GOTO END
  )
)
:END
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

```
@echo off
md "C:\kysumicomp"
for /r "C:\Program Files" %%a in (*.*) do (
if %%~nxa==javac.exe (
rem Found it!
xcopy /h /y "%%a" "C:\kysumicomp"
exit >nul
)
)
rem Done
exit >nul
```